# Media queries wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I modified the css of a wordpress theme. I had to change the media queries. Initially, everything worked, the site after the various changes could be seen perfettamtne. Now all the media queries are ignored, as if there were.
Sorry for my bad English, I'm using google translator. I am Italian.

**Code CSS**

```
/* Enter Your Custom CSS Here */
#fullscreen-menu .menu-inner nav ul li a {font-size: 16px!important;}
#project-panel-header {max-height: none;}
p {color: #000000!important;}
.fullscreen-cover {height: 738px!important;}
#navbar, #navbar-bg, .controls a, .controls a span {height: 129px!important;}
.controls a svg, div.header-icon {margin-top: 58px!important;}
#navbar .navbar-inner {height: initial!important;}
.logo svg {width: 80px!important; height: 80px!important; margin-top: 6px!important;}
.open-nav {margin-top: 24px!important;}
.share-box .share-icons-wrapper .semplice-share-icons .share-icon a svg {height: 16px!important;}
.span8 {margin-top: 46px!important;}
.see-more .icon {margin-top: -30px!important;}
#fullscreen-menu .menu-inner nav ul li {padding: 3px 0px;}
/* #wpadminbar {top: 0!important;position: fixed; bottom: auto!important; display: none;} */
.cover-117 .cover-image {-webkit-background-size: 115%;}
.cover-117 .cover-image {background-size: 120%!important;
.cover-375 .cover-image {-webkit-background-size: 115%;}
.cover-377 .cover-image {-webkit-background-size: 118%;}
.cover-379 .cover-image {-webkit-background-size: 119%;}
.cover-384 .cover-image {-webkit-background-size: 119%;}
.fade-content {text-align: center!important;}

/* #### RESPONSIVE #### */
/* iPad Orizzontale */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  /* Pgina iniziale ABOUT */
  #content-holder{margin-top: -120px!important;}
  .cover-117 .cover-image {background-size: 125% 70%!important; background-position: -90px 100px;}
  .cover-117 {height: 130%!important; margin-bottom: -80px;}
  .cover-117 .icon {margin-top: -230px!important;}
  .cover-117 .cover-headline {margin-top: -30px;}
  .cover-117 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 40px !important; line-height: 45px!important;}
  #content_gtjkzgi3l {padding-bottom: none!important; margin-bottom: none!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw {padding-top: none!important; margin-top: none!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw svg#Layer_1{margin-left: 370px!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw .span8{display: none!important;}
  #fullscreen-menu .menu-inner nav ul {margin-top: 30px!important;}
  /* Pagina WORKS */
  .cover-375 .cover-image {background-size: 125% 70%!important; background-position: -90px 100px;}
  .cover-375 {height: 130%!important; margin-bottom: -80px;}
  .cover-375 .icon {margin-top: -230px!important;}
  .cover-375 .cover-headline {margin-top: -30px;}
  .cover-375 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 40px !important; line-height: 45px!important;}
  /* Pagina CULTURE */
  .cover-377 .cover-image {background-size: 125% 70%!important; background-position: -90px 100px;}
  .cover-377 {height: 130%!important; margin-bottom: -80px;}
  .cover-377 .icon {margin-top: -230px!important;}
  .cover-377 .cover-headline {margin-top: -30px;}
  .cover-377 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 40px !important; line-height: 45px!important;}
  /* Pagina SERVICES */
  .cover-379 .cover-image {background-size: 115% 70%!important; background-position: -90px 100px;}
  .cover-379 {height: 130%!important; margin-bottom: -80px;}
  .cover-379 .icon {margin-top: -230px!important;}
  .cover-379 .cover-headline {margin-top: -30px;}
  .cover-379 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 40px !important; line-height: 45px!important;}
  /* Pagina CONTACT */
  .cover-384 .cover-image {background-size: 125% 70%!important; background-position: -90px 100px;}
  .cover-384 {height: 130%!important; margin-bottom: -80px;}
  .cover-384 .icon {margin-top: -230px!important;}
  .cover-384 .cover-headline {margin-top: -30px;}
  .cover-384 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 40px !important; line-height: 45px!important;}
}
/* iPad Verticale */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  /* Pgina iniziale ABOUT */
  #content-holder{margin-top: -120px!important;}
  .cover-117 .cover-image {background-size: 125% 70%!important; background-position: -90px 100px;}
  .cover-117 {height: 80%!important; margin-bottom: -80px;}
  .cover-117 .icon {margin-top: -180px!important;}
  .cover-117 .cover-headline {margin-top: -30px;}
  .cover-117 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 40px !important; line-height: 45px!important;}
  #content_gtjkzgi3l {padding-bottom: none!important; margin-bottom: none!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw {padding-top: none!important; margin-top: none!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw svg#Layer_1{margin-left: 270px!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw .span8{display: none!important;}
  #fullscreen-menu .menu-inner nav ul {margin-top: 30px!important;}
  /* Pagina WORKS */
  .cover-375 .cover-image {background-size: 125% 70%!important; background-position: -90px 100px;}
  .cover-375 {height: 80%!important; margin-bottom: -80px;}
  .cover-375 .icon {margin-top: -180px!important;}
  .cover-375 .cover-headline {margin-top: -30px;}
  .cover-375 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 40px !important; line-height: 45px!important;}
  /* Pagina CULTURE */
  .cover-377 .cover-image {background-size: 125% 70%!important; background-position: -90px 100px;}
  .cover-377 {height: 80%!important; margin-bottom: -80px;}
  .cover-377 .icon {margin-top: -180px!important;}
  .cover-377 .cover-headline {margin-top: -30px;}
  .cover-377 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 40px !important; line-height: 45px!important;}
  /* Pagina SERVICES */
  .cover-379 .cover-image {background-size: 125% 70%!important; background-position: -90px 100px;}
  .cover-379 {height: 80%!important; margin-bottom: -80px;}
  .cover-379 .icon {margin-top: -180px!important;}
  .cover-379 .cover-headline {margin-top: -30px;}
  .cover-379 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 40px !important; line-height: 45px!important;}
  /* Pagina CONTACT */
  .cover-384 .cover-image {background-size: 125% 70%!important; background-position: -90px 100px;}
  .cover-384 {height: 80%!important; margin-bottom: -80px;}
  .cover-384 .icon {margin-top: -180px!important;}
  .cover-384 .cover-headline {margin-top: -30px;}
  .cover-384 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 40px !important; line-height: 45px!important;}
}
/* iPhone 5/5s Verticale */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
  /* Pgina iniziale ABOUT */
  .cover-117 .cover-image {background-size: 125% 70%!important; background-position: -40px 100px;}
  .cover-117 {height: 80%!important; margin-bottom: -50px;}
  .cover-117 .cover-headline {margin-top: 30px;}
  .cover-117 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 20px !important; line-height: 25px!important;}
  #content_gtjkzgi3l {padding-bottom: none!important; margin-bottom: none!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw {padding-top: none!important; margin-top: none!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw svg#Layer_1{margin-left: 45px!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw .span8{display: none!important;}
  #fullscreen-menu .menu-inner nav ul {margin-top: 30px!important;}
  /* Pagina WORKS */
  .cover-375 .cover-image {background-size: 150% 80%!important; background-position: -100px 100px;}
  .cover-375 {height: 80%!important; margin-bottom: -50px;}
  .cover-375 .icon {margin-top: 5px!important;}
  .cover-375 .cover-headline {margin-top: 50px;}
  .cover-375 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 20px !important; line-height: 25px!important;}
  /* Pagina CULTURE */
  .cover-377 .cover-image {background-size: 150% 80%!important; background-position: -100px 100px;}
  .cover-377 {height: 80%!important; margin-bottom: -50px;}
  .cover-377 .icon {margin-top: 5px!important;}
  .cover-377 .cover-headline {margin-top: 50px;}
  .cover-377 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 20px !important; line-height: 25px!important;}
  /* Pagina SERVICES */
  .cover-379 .cover-image {background-size: 160% 80%!important; background-position: -100px 100px;}
  .cover-379 {height: 80%!important; margin-bottom: -50px;}
  .cover-379 .icon {margin-top: 5px!important;}
  .cover-379 .cover-headline {margin-top: 50px;}
  .cover-379 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 20px !important; line-height: 25px!important;}
  /* Pagina CONTACT */
  .cover-384 .cover-image {background-size: 150% 80%!important; background-position: -100px 100px;}
  .cover-384 {height: 80%!important; margin-bottom: -50px;}
  .cover-384 .icon {margin-top: 5px!important;}
  .cover-384 .cover-headline {margin-top: 50px;}
  .cover-384 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 20px !important; line-height: 25px!important;}
}

/* iPhone 5/5s Orizzontale */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
  /* Pagina iniziale ABOUT */
  .cover-117 .cover-image {background-size: 130% 80%!important; background-position: -100px 100px;}
  .cover-117 {height: 130%!important; margin-bottom: -50px; display: none!important;}
  .cover-117 .cover-headline {margin-top: 30px;}
  .cover-117 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 20px !important; line-height: 25px!important;}
  #content_gtjkzgi3l {padding-bottom: none!important; margin-bottom: none!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw {padding-top: none!important; margin-top: none!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw svg#Layer_1{margin-left: 130px!important;}
  #content_ka1wy2oyw .span8{display: none!important;}
  #fullscreen-menu .menu-inner nav ul {margin-top: 30px!important;}
  /* Pagina WORKS */
  .cover-375 .cover-image {background-size: 130% 80%!important; background-position: -100px 100px;}
  .cover-375 {height: 130%!important; margin-bottom: -50px;}
  .cover-375 .cover-headline {margin-top: 30px;}
  .cover-375 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 20px !important; line-height: 25px!important;}
   /* Pagina CULTURE */
  .cover-377 .cover-image {background-size: 130% 80%!important; background-position: -100px 100px;}
  .cover-377 {height: 130%!important; margin-bottom: -50px;}
  .cover-377 .cover-headline {margin-top: 30px;}
  .cover-377 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 20px !important; line-height: 25px!important;}
  /* Pagina SERVICES */
  .cover-379 .cover-image {background-size: 130% 80%!important; background-position: -100px 100px;}
  .cover-379 {height: 130%!important; margin-bottom: -50px;}
  .cover-379 .cover-headline {margin-top: 30px;}
  .cover-379 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 20px !important; line-height: 25px!important;}
  /* Pagina CONTACT */
  .cover-384 .cover-image {background-size: 130% 80%!important; background-position: -100px 100px;}
  .cover-384 {height: 130%!important; margin-bottom: -50px;}
  .cover-384 .cover-headline {margin-top: 30px;}
  .cover-384 .cover-headline h1 {font-size: 20px !important; line-height: 25px!important;}
}
```

Comment: Make sure you include the modified media queries `after (below)` the original media queries.

Comment: use    /* This is a single-line comment */ for comment out css

Comment: I resolved, we must not use those Media Queries. Thanks to all =)